# Mininet- how to simulate errors?

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking, mininet, ryu

I would like to ask, how can I simulate errors on switches in mininet? Such as rx_errors, tx_errors, dropped packets, collisions, crc errors, frame errors and other. My topology consists of 6 switches, 6 clients, 1 origin and 2 surrogate servers. I am simulating traffic (it works, rx and tx bytes do go up) and I've tried simulating errors by adding loss and delay parameters when adding a link, but I still get 0s at any of the error counters. I also tried using netem to set  corruption, delay and frame reordering, applied to all ports on all switches and nothing. I am using Ryu's switch `simple_switch_stp_13` and controller `ofctl_rest`. I send http requests to all switches to get the info about ports every 5 seconds.